# Parsing multiple xml files in folder then write to central csv

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and have written the following code to parse multiple xml files in a directory and write the content to a central CSV file.

I have a folder with approximately 30 xml files. My issue is that it is only grabbing content from the first xml in the folder but not the rest. I think I have an issue with not having a loop? I am using Beautifulsoup and would like to stick to this as I have built understanding of it.

```
#open beautifulsoup library AND csv function

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import glob

#Open and read files in folder ending with .xml
for filename in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    with open(filename) as open_file:
        content = open_file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

#open and write csv file

csv_file = open('scrape.csv', 'a')
post_line = ['postid', 'subreddit', 'post title', 'author', 'post url', 'post date', 'post time', 'post score', 'submission text']
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(post_line)

#grab content from xml from following textblocks
#postid

for postid in soup.find('textblock', tid='7').text:
pid = postid.split(':')[1]
print(pid)

#subreddit
for subreddit in soup.find('textblock', tid='15').text
subred = subreddit.split(':')[1]
print(subred)

#post title
for posttitle in soup.find('textblock', tid='12').text
ptitle = posttitle.split(':')[1]
print(ptitle)

#author
for username in soup.find('textblock', tid='0').text
author = username.split(':')[1]
print(author)

#post url
for posturl in soup.find('textblock', tid='13').text
url = posturl.split(':')[2]
purl = f'https:{url}'
print(purl)

#post date
for postdate in soup.find('textblock', tid='3').text
pdate = postdate.split()[1]
print(pdate)

#post time
for posttime in soup.find('textblock', tid='3').text
ptime = posttime.split()[2]
print(ptime)

#post score
for postscore in soup.find('textblock', tid='10').text
pscore = postscore.split(':')[1]
print(pscore)

#submission text
for submission in soup.find('textblock', tid='20').text
print(submission)

#blank space
print()

csv_writer.writerow([pid, subred, ptitle, author, purl, pdate, ptime, pscore, submission])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: you have to do it inside your `for`-loop - similar like you get `soup = ...` . Except opeingi `csv` file. You have to open `csv` (and write headers) before `for`-loop. And close it after `for`-loop

Comment: I don't know why you use all there `for` with `find(..).text` because `find(..).text` should give you single string and `for` get chars (one-by-one) from this string and `print()` should display every char in seperated line.

Comment: Can you share XML snippet and explain what is the data you want to extract from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only use the soup of the last file.

```
...
for filename in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    with open(filename) as open_file:
        content = open_file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')    # overwrite soup with the soup of current file
...
# handle soup
```

you could make handle_soup a function and call it on every soup.

```
import glob
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csv_file = open('scrape.csv', 'a')
post_line = ['postid', 'subreddit', 'post title', 'author', 'post url', 'post date', 'post time', 'post score', 'submission text']
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(post_line)

def handle_soup(soup, csv_writer):
    pid = soup.find('textblock', tid='7').text.split(":")[1]
    print(pid)

    subred = soup.find('textblock', tid='15').text.split(':')[1]
    print(subred)
    ...     # replace ... with other items
    csv_writer.writerow([pid, subred, ...]) # replace ... with other items


for filename in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    with open(filename) as open_file:
        content = open_file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        handle_soup(soup, csv_writer)

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. You gave an example for pid which is the first column of the csv. Do i copy that handle soup code for the remaining columns? Like below:

def handle_soup(soup, writer):
    pid = soup.find('textblock', tid='7').text.split(":")[1]
    print(pid)
    ...
    writer.writerow([pid, ...])

def handle_soup(soup, writer):
    subred = soup.find('textblock', tid='15').text.split(":")[1]
    print(subred)
    ...
    writer.writerow([subred, ...])

Comment: see edit, handle_soup assumes that every soup loads one textblock per item per file.

Comment: Great! I know this will work but at this stage the code is stopping before it can finish due to two errors: 1) 'UnicodeDecodeError: charmap codec can't decode byte, and 2) if the textblock doesn't exist or if is empty then I get errors. I believe this is due to some xml's being deleted posts and therefore some fields are empty. Can you please help?

Comment: i might, but it is probably best to accept this answer and ask a new question so other people can chime in as well, you may tag me in your new question.